# How to define a conditioned function that returns one when x is integer and zero otherwise?

Tags: function-construction

What is the simplest way to define a **conditioned** function that returns one when x is integer and zero otherwise?

I'm doing it wrong:

```
g[x_] := 1 /; floor[x] == x
g[x_] := 0 /; floor[x] <> x
g[2]
g[2.5]
```

Gives result:

```
1
1
```

Comment: Didn't you notice the error messages?

Comment: @JohnDoty No. I'm a beginner. I see no error when evaluating notebook. Maybe it's disabled by default.

Comment: all internal Mathematica functions start with an uppercase letter. This also holds for Floor.

Comment: Be aware there are subtle issues dealing with real values that are approximately integers. You may be surprised to find   `Floor[ 1.00000000000001 ]==1.00000000000001` yields `True`.  If that issue is important you need to specify what result you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g = Boole @* IntegerQ;

g /@ {-2, 3, 1.7, foo, "bar"}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

---

Responding to the comment, this is your code corrected:

```
ClearAll[g]

g[x_] := 1 /; Floor[x] == x
g[x_] := 0 /; Floor[x] != x
g[2]
g[2.5]
```

> ```
> 1
>
> 0
> ```

1. Capitalization is important in *Mathematica.*  Nearly all System Symbols begin with a capital letter.
2. `<>` is a shorthand infix operator for [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html).  Use `!=` for [`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) instead.

Comment: That's good answer. But I don't understand what's wrong with my way of doing this.

Comment: @pusheax You didn't ask what you did wrong but instead for the "simplest way" so I answered that.  But I'll edit my answer to include that also.

Comment: Awesome. ClearAll also helped. Without it it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    g[x_] := If[IntegerQ[x], 1, 0];
g[2]
g[2.5]
```

giving

```
(*
 1
 0
*)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Overloading can do the trick too:

```
g[x_Integer] = 1;
g[x_] = 0;
```

Comment: I think I would write this as `g[_Integer] = 1; g[___] = 0;`

Comment: That's better indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `2.0` to be recognized as an integer you may use:

```
g[x_] := Boole[NumericQ@x && Last@Internal`TestIntegerQ@x]

g /@ {-2, 2.0, 3, 1.7, foo, "bar"}
(* {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0} *)
```